# SelectBoxIt - Multiple selects on page (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a page that has to have multiple select boxes if needed. I'm using [this plugin](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) to style the selectbox.

```
$('body').on('click', '.add_option.add_title', function() {
    $('.add_title_option').after($('.add_title_option .controls').html());
});
```

This is my javascript that I "clone" the selectbox and add it after it.

```
<div class="add_title_option">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="title" name="title">
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">Option #1</option>
                <option value="2">Option #2</option>
                <option value="3">Option #3</option>
                <option value="4">Option #4</option>
            </select>
            <a href="javascript:false;" class="add_option add_title">
                <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/img/add_options.png" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="error" id="title_error"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does "clone" itselfs, but the select is not functional.

How should I do it to add multiple selects through javascript?

Comment: what do you mean by "not functional"?

Comment: The style is shown, but the "select" doesn't do anything: on click doesn't display the options, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.add_option.add_title', function() {
    $('.add_title_option').after($('#title').clone());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
$('.add_title_option').after($('.selectContainer select').clone().show());
```

Insted of

```
$('.add_title_option').after($('.add_title_option .controls').html());
```

In order to clone it, and set display from none to show.
Then you have to transform your select box with `.selectBoxIt()`

To customize it with this plugin.
Also, I have removed the id from select box to be sure we will not have dublicated ids.
Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/css/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/js/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

    $(".titleSelect").selectBoxIt();

    $('body').on('click', '#dublicateButton', function() {
        $('.add_title_option').after($('.selectContainer select').clone().show().selectBoxIt());

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="add_title_option">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="selectContainer" >
                <select class="titleSelect" name="title">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option #3</option>
                    <option value="4">Option #4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:void(null);" id="dublicateButton" class="add_option add_title">
                click
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="error" id="title_error"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```